# « Meilleur de » ou « mieux de » ?

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes, comparatifs

Doit-on dire :

> C'est mieux d'aller au cinéma.

ou

> C'est meilleur d'aller au cinéma.

?

Pourquoi « meilleur » ? La perspective d'aller au cinéma est meilleure que celle de ne pas y aller. C'est le meilleur choix.

Pourquoi « mieux » ? C'est ce que je trouve dans mon manuel de grammaire... (*Grammaire du Français*, Delatour, Jennepin, Léon-Dufour, Mattlé, Teyssier, Hachette, 1991, p. 186)

Comment: *C'est moins bien d'aller au cinéma* ou *c'est moins bon d'aller au cinéma* ?

Comment: @jlliagre: Je ne sais pas. *moins bon*? Le français est une langue étrangère pour moi. En anglais on dirait *better* - *worse*, qui sont à la fois adjectifs et adverbes.

Comment: L'anglais n'a guère que le mot *good* pour traduire bon et bien. C'est bien dommage car il n'est pas facile d'expliquer quand utiliser bon et quand utiliser bien. Ici, seul bien donc mieux sont idiomatiques. C'est meilleur ("plus bon") sous-entendrait qu'aller au cinéma procure un plaisir gustatif ou physique.

Answer (score 2):

Il faudrait tout d'abord un contexte à ces phrases.

Si on discute les plaisirs respectifs que l'on dérive de certaines activités, telles que passer un moment dans un parc d'attractions, dans une fête foraine, aller danser, etc. on pourra utiliser « bon » plutôt que « bien ». En utilisant « meilleur », comme ce mot est le comparatif de supériorité de « bon » on insiste sur la qualité de l'apport qui résulte d'aller au cinéma, alors que si l'on utilise « mieux » on peut englober des critères subjectifs dans ce que l'on caractérise par cet adjectif. Par exemple, si dans une soirée donnée on a à décider laquelle des activités considérées ci-dessus est le « bon » choix et que l'on est plutôt fatigué, que l'on se sent les jambes lourdes, on dira, il me semble, sans hésiter, « C'est mieux d'aller au cinéma. » et non « C'est meilleur…». Le contexte présent est courant,  pas très recherché. Il existe d'autres contextes, plus subtil, je crois, dans lesquels un choix similaire sera encore le plus judicieux.