# Je suis mieux, je suis meilleur

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

Bonjour, je voulais savoir si on dit "Je suis mieux en anglais" ou "Je suis meilleur en anglais".

Je pense qu'on doit dire meilleur parce qu'on utilise être? C'est pas facile, parce que je sais qu'on dit "Je parle mieux" et mieux est un adverbe ici, je suis confus. J'ai trouvé les deux exemples en ligne, ça ne m'aide pas. Aidez-moi s'il vous plaît, merci !

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-meilleur-et-mieux https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-to-know-when-to-use-bon-or-bien https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19730/meilleur-or-mieux-for-it-will-be-better https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36717/are-you-supposed-to-say-quelqu-un-de-mieux-or-quelqu-un-de-meilleur https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41495/i-will-get-better https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/meilleur-de-ou-mieux-de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il est souvent difficile de deviner le sens de phrases en l'absence de contexte mais voici comment on peut interpréter celles de la question :

> 1. **Je suis mieux** en anglais.

« J'ai fait des progrès en anglais » (registre relâché)
« J'apprécie plus les cours d'anglais » (c-à-d « Je me sens mieux en anglais »)
« Ma prestation est meilleure quand je m'exprime ou suis doublé en anglais »
...

*I feel better in English, I look better in English.*

Bien que "je suis mieux" soit une tournure relativement récente et plutôt relâchée, en voici une occurrence ancienne et littéraire :

***Je suis mieux en tout** quand je me contiens*. Mme de Stael, Delphine, 1802.

> 2. **Je suis meilleur** en anglais

« Mon niveau en anglais est supérieur à mon niveau dans une autre matière »
« En anglais, mon niveau est supérieur à celui de quelqu'un d'autre ».

*I'm better in English*.

La deuxième tournure est beaucoup plus courante.

Comment: About your second example for "je suis mieux en anglais", an interesting way of understanding it is to replace it with "je me sens mieux en (cours d')anglais". That's also the way we use it in sports, e.g. : "J'ai mal joué au 1er set, mais j'étais mieux dans le 2e set".

Comment: @Reyedy Ajouté, merci. PS: *Tu es mieux en anglais ?* ;-)

Comment: Depuis que je regarde des séries, je sens que je suis mieux !

Comment: _Je suis mieux_ n'est pas correct selon moi.
Je dirais _Je m'améliore_ à la place.

Comment: @Kii J'ai écrit que c'était du registre relâché. La question ne porte pas sur l'éventuelle correction ou non des expressions, mais sur leur usage. De toute façon, *je suis mieux* s'entend suffisamment pour ne pas (ou plus) être considéré comme incorrect.

Comment: Si tant est que ça l'ait jamais été...

Comment: @Kii Une phrase courante avec *je suis mieux* est ***je suis mieux en vrai***. On ne peut absolument pas y remplacer *je suis mieux* pas *je m'améliore*.

Answer (score 4):

On dit « Je suis meilleur en anglais. ». (Je suis bon en anglais.)

On dit « Je parle mieux. » parce que l'on dit «  parler bien. » et jamais « parler bon. ».

Non, « être » ou le verbe, quel qu'il soit, n'a rien à voir là-dedans.  Ce qui détermine
le comparatif c'est l'usage, c'est à dire l'adjectif que l'on utilise d'habitude.  In French « bon » et « bien » ont chacun leur comparatif, à la différence de l'anglais qui n'a que « better » pour les deux.

Voir cette [page](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-6915.php).